# Why is the Sencha Ext.List component not recognized

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to use the "Ext.dataview.List" in my sencha application, but I'm receiving the following error when loading the page that contains the component:

```
Uncaught Error: [Ext.create] Unrecognized class name / alias: Ext.List
```

I tried to add multiple requires to the page (Ext.dataview.List, the ones listed in the "Requires" of the component documentation..) but without success. I'm kinda lost on what could be happening, and I haven't found any specific information of what could be the problem. I've never had this problem with another components, just indicating the "xtype" works okay.

Someone has an idea of which can be the problem?

I'm creating the component like this, with sencha version 6.2:

```
var list = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    fullscreen: true,
    itemTpl: '{title}',
    data: [
        { title: 'Item 1' },
        { title: 'Item 2' },
        { title: 'Item 3' },
        { title: 'Item 4' }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Make sure you are using modern part of the framework, Ext.List doesn't seem to exist in classic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Two toolkits for EXJS : Classic and Modern. The Classic Toolkit is essentially Ext JS 5’s view layer and is used to create Desktop applications.
The Modern Toolkit is for targeting modern browsers from Desktop to Mobile and, at this stage, is made up of Sencha Touch’s view layer.

Currently there is no "EXt.List" in Classic toolkit. To solve this problem make sure you're using the Modern version or change your approach to your desired result.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the problem. I haven't noticed that the component documentation is specific for modern toolkit; I assumed that I had it in Classic too basically because it doesn't seem too complex. I will look for another alternative.

Comment: You're welcom. Good luck.